# Boto3 CloudFormation Status

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to get the status of a CloudFormation stack? If so, how?

I'm creating a stack with:

```
client = boto3.client('cloudformation',)
response = client.create_stack(
    StackName=stackname,
    ...
)
```

I can see in the CloudFormation web UI that the stack successfully creates.

I've tried to get the status with:

```
print(client.describe_stacks(stack_name_or_id=hostname))
```

But that throws exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "stack_name_or_id", must be one of: StackName, NextToken
```

So I tried to wait while the stack deploys and catch the exception with:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        print(client.describe_stacks(stack_name_or_id=stackname))
    except botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError:
        pass
```

But I get no response at all; the `print` statement never gets called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message:

```
Unknown parameter in input: "stack_name_or_id", must be one of: StackName, NextToken
```

clearly says you are passing invalid parameter name; `stack_name_or_id`.

In [Boto3 describe_stacks](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.describe_stacks), the expected parameter is: `StackName`

```
response = client.describe_stacks(
    StackName='string',
    NextToken='string'
)
```

For a running stack, you can pass stack name or stack ID. But for deleted stacks, you have to pass stack ID.

```
client.describe_stacks(StackName='mystack')

{u'Stacks': [{u'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:.......
  'content-type': 'text/xml', 
  'date': 'Thu, 22 Jun 2017 14:54:46 GMT'}}}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried using the stack id. Same error: Unknown parameter in input: "stack_name_or_id", must be one of: StackName, NextToken

Comment: The thing is; it is neither running nor deleted when I'm trying to get the status...

Comment: @KarimTabet, you are missing the point. You have to pass `StackName`, not `stack_name_or_id`. You are focusing on parameter value instead of parameter name.

Comment: Yep. You were right. Totally missed the point. Sorry I wasn't thinking straight.